# Perform a modulus in a huge number?

Tags: .net, modulo

I need to do a modulus operation on very large integers.  The biggest integer supported by my platform (edit: .NET 2.0) is a 64 bit integer, which aren't big enough for the numbers I'm working with.

How can I do a modulus on really big integers, like 12654875632126424875387321657498462167853687516876876?

I have a solution that treats the number as a string and works it in pieces one by one, but I wanted to know if there's a better way.

Here's my function treating the number as a string.  It basically does long division the way you'd do it by hand.

```
    Public Function MyMod(ByVal numberString As String, ByVal modby As Integer) As Integer
        Dim position As Integer = -1
        Dim curSubtraction As Integer = 0

        While position < numberString.Length - 1
            position += 1
            curSubtraction = curSubtraction * 10 + CInt(numberString.Substring(position, 1))

            If (curSubtraction / modby) < 1 And position = numberString.Length - 1 Then
                Return curSubtraction
            ElseIf (curSubtraction / modby) < 1 Then
                Continue While
            Else
                curSubtraction = curSubtraction Mod modby
            End If
        End While
        Return curSubtraction
    End Function
```

Is there a cleaner, more efficient way?

EDIT: To clarify, the integers are coming from IBAN bank account numbers.  According to the specification, you have to convert the IBAN account number (containing letters) into one integer.  Then, you do a modulus on the integer.  So, I guess you could say that the real source of the integer to perform the modulus on is a string of digits.

Comment: What language is this?  You might want to add a tag.

Comment: It would also be helpful to include an example.  Do you have the solution to the huge number in your question mod by some other value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't specified where the numbers are coming from, but you might be able to make some simplifications.  If the numbers are originally smaller, then consider things like:

```
(a + b) MOD n = ((a MOD n) + (b MOD n)) MOD n
```

or

```
ab MOD n = (a MOD n)(b MOD n) MOD n
```

Comment: Yes--I needed to clarify the question better.  Your solution would work if I started with multiple integers, but in my case I'm starting with one big integer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a crypto/math library.  Google for bignum.

Answer (score 0):

You need an arbitrary-precision integer math library such as [IntX](http://www.codeplex.com/IntX/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4, you can just use a BigInteger. But here is how to do it with earlier versions.

There is a mathematical trick with mods where you can just take the first *x* number of digits, calculate the mod on that value, then prepend the *result* of that mod back onto the leftover digits, and keep repeating the process until you reach the end of your "huge" number.

Bring on the recursive method! (Sorry I don't do VB)

```
private static int Mod(string value, int mod) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value.", "value");
    if (mod <= 0) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid mod.", "mod");

    int maxLength = long.MaxValue.ToString().Length - 1;

    return value.Length > maxLength
        ? Mod((Convert.ToInt64(value.Substring(0, maxLength)) % mod).ToString() + value.Substring(maxLength), mod)
        : Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToInt64(value) % mod);}
```